# Does container.clear() free/reallocate internal buffers?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a container and call `clear()` on it, does that *just* destruct all of the elements inside or does it actually free/allocate new memory internally too? Is this behavior outside the scope of the C++ standard?

This boils down to:

```
unordered_set<int> mySet { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
mySet.reserve(1000);
mySet.clear();

//Is this pointless/redundant
//or should I treat my container like it was just constructed?
mySet.reserve(1000);
```

A quick test on ideone (http://ideone.com/XQi8IT) shows that the internal memory buffer is retained after a call to clear. So, at least for new versions of g++ on `unordered_set` that is the case. My question goes to 1) what the standard says, if anything and 2) whether this behavior is consistent across all containers.

Comment: It is not specified. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/. Hence (for vectors), you might use shrink_to_fit

Comment: @Cyber - The `resize` method does not apply to `unordered_set` and other containers. This question is more general, it is also asking something different. Interesting read though - thanks.

Comment: @Mark It depends on the container -- for example, tree structures such as `std::map` don't have a capacity. When you remove a value from the tree, that node is destroyed immediately and so `clear()` would free all of the allocated internal nodes.

Comment: `clear` doesn't change capacity. That's what `reserve` is [for](http://ideone.com/vlnugR).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's unspecified with what happens to the memory. It just defines the following requirements:

For sequence containers we have the following requirements for `clear()`:

`[C++11 §23.2.3]` Table 100

> Destroys all elements in `a`. Invalidates all references, pointers,
>   and iterators referring to the elements of `a` and may invalidate the
>   past-the-end iterator.
>
> post: `a.empty()` returns `true`

Which doesn't really mention anything about memory. For associate containers we have this requirement for `clear()`:

`[C++11 §23.2.4]` Table 102

> `a.erase(a.begin(),a.end())`

Which leads to `erase(...)` requirements which are:

> erases the element pointed to by `q`. Returns an iterator pointing to the element immediately following `q` prior to the element being erased. If no such element exists, returns `a.end()`

Which again, mentions nothing about the capacity of the memory buffer of the container. Then we have unordered associate containers which have similar wording:

`[C++11 §23.2.5]` Table 103

> Erases all elements in the container. Post: `a.empty()` returns `true`

Overall, the standard doesn't mention anything happens to the internal memory buffers after `clear`. So that's unspecified behaviour that could vary amongst different implementations.

Since `reserve` is not available in all containers (which does change the capacity) and neither is the next best thing (`shrink_to_fit`) there doesn't seem to be a good way to consistently clear out the internal memory of a container.

Comment: Upvoted.  libc++ and libstdc++ preserve `bucket_count()` across a `clear()`.  VS-2015 does not.

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement in the C++ standard for any standard container to free any memory. Even the function `std::vector<T>::shrink_to_fit()` only requests the shrinking of memory. This function is thought to replace idioms like

```
std::vector<T>().swap( myVector );
```

This idiom was used to really free memory, which is not guaranteed by `std::vector<T>::clear()`. (In fact, `std::vector<T>::clear()` is specified to leave the `capacity()` unchanged.) You can still use this idiom for other containers though, which do not have a function `shrink_to_fit()`.